# Binding text view to database in android

Tags: android, database, textview

How do I bind a text view to the database in android ? I want to do it in such a way that changes in the database reflect in the text view. All the solutions seem to be only for list view(SimpleCursorAdapter). Does anyone have one for this ?

Comment: Even in the case of using a SimpleCursorAdapter with a ListView, it is my understanding that if the database is changed, the cursor will NOT be updated unless you call `requery()`... so it isn't automatic. Someone correct me if I am wrong here but I don't think that binding does what you think it will.